# How might I replace the outer contents of a string using regex?

Tags: php, regex, html, laravel, visual-studio-code

Suppose I had the code (or string) :

```
{ if 1 == 1 }Middle Part{ /if }
```

Then, say I want to replace all instances of

```
{ if 1 == 1 }Middle Part{ /if }
```

with

```
@if(1 == 1)Middle Part@endif
```

Conceptually, which tool (or regex principle) would I need to apply, to replace everything around text that I want to preserve?

I want to find strings that start with `{if ... }` and end with `{/if}`, and then replace the first value `{if ... }` with `@if( ... )` and the second value, `{/if}` with `@endif`, but I do not want to touch the 'Middle Part' text. I also first need to find strings that start with `{if' and end with '}` and replace with `@if(' and with ')`

Symbolically, if I have ABC, I want to have a mapping of the A part, the B part, and the C part, but only replace A and C to their mappings, A->X and C->Z

I am basically trying to quickly convert a template file from one template language to another (in this case, Smarty (.tpl) to Blade (.blade.php)).

It has been a bit since I have done regular expressions beyond simple text find and replace. I know I can do this programatically, but I was wondering if there was a tool to already take care of these patterns.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the minimal structure like your sample string and capture the two variable parts into two groups using `(.*?)`,

```
{\s*if\s*(.*?)\s*}(.*?){\s*\/if\s*}
```

and then replace it with following, which will preserve your variable parts and put everything in the new structure like you want,

```
@if($1)$2@endif
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/f4SLO7/1)**

[PHP Code demo](https://rextester.com/QWLEU29840)

```
$s = '{ if 1 == 1 }Middle Part{ /if }';
echo preg_replace('/{\s*if\s*(.*?)\s*}(.*?){\s*\/if\s*}/', '@if($1)$2@endif', $s);
```

Prints,

```
@if(1 == 1)Middle Part@endif
```

On another note, you should **ONLY** use this, in case your structures aren't nested. In case of nested ones, you may better be off writing your own custom parser as regex won't suffice in that case.